# React Virtualized - onclick, expand Rows for additional details

Tags: reactjs, react-virtualized

I have a requirement to open/close additional row details.

Has anyone implemented or have ideas on how to go about implementing expand/collapse feature for each row?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There's a template of sorts for this sort of thing ([demo](https://rawgit.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/master/playground/tree.html), [source](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/blob/master/playground/tree.js)) The important bit is that you'll need to tell your `List`/`Grid`/whatever when an open/close has changed (aka when size might have changed), eg:

```
this._listRef.recomputeRowHeights(indexOfChangedRow) // Clear cached size
this._listRef.forceUpdateGrid() // Rerender list with new size
```

Comment: Thank You, i was able to get this working by customizing the RowRenderer file and your demo and suggestions. Much appreciated!

Comment: @brianvaughn Thank you for answer but I can't implement this solution on Virtualized Grid, Grid don't have *recomputeRowHeights* method

Comment: Please read the documentation. `Grid` defines a similar method named `cellRangeRenderer`.

https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/blob/master/docs/Grid.md

Comment: resurrecting this old thread. 
@bvaughn if I understand correctly the example you provided doesn't support virtualization for nested items, correct? I mean if there are a lot of sub-items then they all will be added to the DOM if parent item is visible. Is there a better approach to support virtualization in sub items too ?

Answer (score 5):

I was looking for the same feature, but I did not find some useful results as I searched, maybe this sandbox helps others looking for a similar feature in their apps:

The example is using `Table` from `react-virtualized` beside `react hooks`.

[Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/71l1zkrqmx)